# Regex replace part of file name jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string which follows the same pattern. I need to dynamically set the first digits of the file name within this string.

Example:

```
var newNumber = '123';
```

Change this

```
var str = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/567-7-P.jpg'
```

To this

```
var newStr = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/123-7-P.jpg'
```

I have written a few simple jQuery lines to break apart the string but not quite sure on how to rebuild it again with the new value. I would prefer to do this more neatly using rgex but my regex skills are limited.

Current state http://jsfiddle.net/j2qLvqbw/

Comment: Please post your code in addition to the fiddle.

Comment: How stable is the pattern for the file name? Will the first few digits always be followed by a dash? Can we be sure that the folder names don't match the same pattern?

Comment: @tvanfosson The pattern is guaranteed to match this. The only difference may be the number of digits wont alway be 3 in length. The positioning will always be that of the examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following finds and replaces the first occurrence of a slash, followed by a group of digits, followed by a dash with `/123-'`  If you need it to be parameterized for different replacement strings, simply construct the replacement string dynamically with the replacement values. http://jsfiddle.net/0bqwxf0p/

```
var path = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/567-7-P.jpg'

var newPath = path.replace(/\/\d+-/, '/123-');
```

Comment: I want to note that this replacement is specific to the pattern that the OP indicates will be followed. In particular if the folder names might also match the format of the file name, this method won't work.  It will match on the folder rather than the file.  Anchoring the replacement string to a slash, followed by digits, followed by a dash hopefully makes this resilient in the OPs case but might not be a good match for anyone else.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly for my needs and much cleaner than my approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/567-7-P.jpg';
var newvalue = '123';
var result = string.substr(string.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var sections = result.split('-');
var replaceit = string.replace(sections[0], newvalue);
$('p').text(replaceit);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j2qLvqbw/2/)

you can use it as a function

```
function replcaeNum(imgurl , newvalue){
    var result = imgurl.substr(imgurl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var sections = result.split('-');
    var replaceit = imgurl.replace(sections[0], newvalue);
    $('p').text(replaceit);
}
```

and use it like that

```
// replcaeNum(imgurl ,newvalue);
replcaeNum('/folder1/folder2/folder3/567-7-P.jpg','123');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j2qLvqbw/4/)

Comment: You're making a big assumption that the value won't appear anywhere else in the string.  What if one of the folder names happens to contain the same value?

Comment: @tvanfosson 100% of programming work with if statement .. so if I open my mind to assumed everything for OP different cases .. It will be better to make his homework instead of him .. I already answered the case he asked for with his demo link .. and as you know  programming learned with problems  .. Let him try and if he got another problem .. may be yes may be no .. he will ask again till he learn and stop asking .. sorry for bad english :)

Comment: I disagree, you're the one who is making assumptions about the state of the data and failing to account for the obvious possibility that your string replacement might have significant unintended consequences.  It's the nature of the type of string replacement that you've done that doesn't account for and anchor the replacement to the specific part of the string needing to be replaced that is the problem. Not accounting for this in your answer is a bit like being ok with teaching your child about a hot stove by letting him or her get burned.

Comment: @tvanfosson I got your point.. and I will take that in consider in my next answers .. Now I just hope that the OP not get burned after my code :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

This regex uses ([^/]+$) to make sure you don't match a folder instead of a file if both follow the same pattern:

```
var path = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/567-7-P.jpg';
var newPath = string.replace(/\/\d+([^\/]+)$/, "/123$1");

// result: '/folder1/folder2/folder3/123-7-P.jpg';
```

If there's a folder with the same pattern:

```
var path = '/folder1/folder2/987-abc/567-7-P.jpg';
```

the regex will only replace the file name:

```
// result: '/folder1/folder2/987-abc/123-7-P.jpg';
```

Comment: Thanks, clean approach. Would this work if the string was `'/folder1/folder2/folder3/67-7-P.jpg'` ?

Comment: Yes, it would work. The ([^\/]+) part matches any character that is not a slash and stores it in $1.

Comment: Oops, now it does. I've replaced \d{3} with \d+.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.split()` , `.splice()`

```js
var newNumber = "123";
var str = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/567-7-P.jpg";
// `.split` "/"
var res = str.split("/");
// `.splice` last index within `res` , `.replace` first occurrence
// of digit followed by "-" with `newNumber`
res.splice(-1, 1, res.slice(-1)[0].replace(/\d+(?=-)/, newNumber));
var newStr = res.join("/");
document.write(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon your example:

```
var string = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/567-7-P.jpg';

var path = string.substr(0, string.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var filename = string.substr(string.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var separator = filename.indexOf('-');
var suffix = filename.substr(separator, filename.length); // -7-P.jpg

$('p').text(path + '123' + suffix);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j2qLvqbw/11/